# Git commit could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, git

I'm experiencing 'permission denied' in my own repo in a shared server.
I tried some found solutions from other stacks and it did not solve my issue.

Is there anything else I should be trying?

```
-bash-4.1$ chown -R $(whoami) .git
-bash-4.1$ git commit -m "added some more scripts"
fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied
-bash-4.1$ chmod 777 .git
-bash-4.1$ git commit -m "added some more scripts"
fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied
-bash-4.1$ ls -al .git
total 9
drwxrwxrwx  13 yj2429 dune  512 Sep  3 11:27 .
drwxr-xr-x  44 yj2429 dune  512 Sep  3 11:11 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 yj2429 dune   19 Sep  3 11:13 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rw-r--r--   1 yj2429 dune   23 Aug  2 14:04 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x   2 yj2429 dune  512 Aug  2 14:04 branches
-rw-r--r--   1 yj2429 dune  261 Aug  2 14:44 config
-rw-r--r--   1 yj2429 dune   73 Aug  2 14:04 description
drwxr-xr-x  13 yj2429 dune  512 Aug  2 14:04 hooks
-rw-r--r--   1 yj2429 dune 2773 Sep  3 11:27 index
drwxr-xr-x   3 yj2429 dune  512 Aug  2 14:04 info
drwxr-xr-x   4 yj2429 dune  512 Sep  3 11:02 logs
drwxr-xr-x 241 yj2429 dune  512 Sep  3 10:52 objects
drwxr-xr-x   5 yj2429 dune  512 Aug  2 14:44 refs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rm .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG 
rm .git/logs/HEAD
rm .git/logs/refs/heads/master
```

seems like a quick fix ...

Comment: Welcome. Please explain what this will do for someone who may not be familiar with these commands.